# How can I make this "rip" for only one edge of a spiral notebook paper?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

[image]
I have made the rest of the paper with holes made from a plane and a boolean modifier. I want to make the paper like it has been ripped from a spiral notebook. Is there any way other than manual modelling to achieve this look?

I have absolutely no idea even where to begin with this.

I did play around with Noise Texture coupled with the Gradient Texture, with this I got the Gradient with Noise on the left edge of the paper. But I could not apply it along with the paper image texture. Also could not make it transparent along the edge to create the rip.

Comment: don't you want to do it with the alpha channel? but of course with that solution you won't have any thickness...

Comment: I am fine with the thickness aspect of it all, it's going to be a top-down shot at the end. I just couldn't rip the paper at the left edge like image attached.

Comment: if you don't need thickness, just use the alpha channel to create the transparency

Comment: I'll do that. Do you have any advice on how to get the tear look like image attached? Noise Texture is ripping the paper along the entire left edge unlike how a paper rips from a spiral notebook, only at the places where there are holes for the spiral binding.
I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try some variation on this..

The page is an *Array*, one hole per element, with caps to give a margin top and bottom:

[image]

.. the element's vertices are added to a 'Tear' vertex group. The group increases the probability that a face will be deleted, and (lazily) is also used as a strength-factor in the random distortion of remaining faces. Playing with the weights will change the characteristics of the tear.

To create the tear, the vertex group is fed as a parameter to a GN modifier:

[image]

*Musgrave Noise* is used to remove faces, and *White Noise* to crinkle remaining geometry discontinuously. There's also a *UV Map* attribute fed to the GN group. (There's a UV offset in the *Array* modifiers, per-element, and per-page. Used like this. they muddle the distribution of damage)

I'm imagining you could tweak this to suit your purposes, apply all the modifiers you need, and keep the pages you like as fixed objects..

[image]

[image]

Comment: very interesting solution!

Comment: Gross...ly entertaining

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!
This taught me a lot about GeoNodes!

Comment: Very nice :) A congrats to diamond jewel :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need any thickness you can use the alpha channel. First give transparency to the background in an image editor software, save as PNG:

[image]

Create a plane in Blender, give it a material with *Image Texture* node, load the image, plug the alpha output into the alpha input of the *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This will serve my purpose for the time being. Do you know about a way to create the left edge entirely procedural? With Shader Nodes or GeoNodes? Because I will need some variations and may not find same textures with different tears. Thank you for help!

Comment: I don't know, I hope a Geonode master will help  ;)